# Cannot get basic index.js to work in simple mocha test project

Tags: javascript, import

I have a simple project laid out like:

```
project
│   package.json    
│
└───productA
│   │
│   └───test
│       │   spec1.js
│   
└───common
    index.js
    │
    └───sharedFunction1
        │   auth.js
        │   index.js
```

In spec1.js, I can successfully import a function from auth.js like this:

```
import { some_function } from "../../common/sharedFunction1/auth.js"
```

However, I thought that I should be able to use index.js files so that I can import like this:

```
import { some_function } from "../../common"
```

The function I am trying to import is something like (just a simple example):

```
export function get_file_listing (folder) {
    var files = fs.readdirSync(folder);
    return files
}
```

and my index.js under sharedFunction1 looks like:

```
export * from './auth';
```

and my index.js under common looks like:

```
export * from "./sharedFunction1";
```

VSCode auto import in the spec file seems to think the import should be:

```
import { some_function } from "../../common";
```

But when I run my test with that I get:

```
Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT]: Directory import ... is not supported resolving ES modules imported from ...
```

My package.json has:

```
  "type": "module",
```

I have read a hundred different pages trying to understand what I am doing wrong, but am stuck.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or if this should even work?

Answer (score 0):

Found that I apparently need this file:

.mocharc.json

```
{
    "node-option": [
        "experimental-specifier-resolution=node"
    ]
}
```